# Virtualbox Ubuntu guest on Windows 7 host with ssd settings?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ssd

I recently switched my harddrive to an ssd.  I am wondering, do I need to do anything when using Virtualbox and Ubuntu (guest) on a Windows 7 host?

I know that for Windows 7 defragmentation and indexing should be turned off.  But how about Ubuntu?  I am not familiar with Ubuntu and don't know if running it in a virtual machine makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu don't use defragmentation so there is no need to turn it off. But you can disable some features.. see [this guide](http://opentechnow.blogspot.com/2010/02/linux-ssd-optimization-guide.html).